# Populating an email with data from IBM i (AS400) screen

Tags: vbscript, outlook, ibm-midrange, mailto

I'm trying to grab data from an AS400 screen & populate an email using that data but seem to have bumped into something I'm struggling to overcome. Here's a slice of what I have so far:

```
Dim polNo
polNo = GetText(10,18,10)

Dim wsh
Set wsh=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

subSub1_()
sub subSub1_()

// Just doing this to check the text I have
SendKeys(polNo)

// Sent the eMail with the text
wsh.Run "mailto:testing@somemailbox.com?Subject=" & polNo

end sub
```

With the above, the resulting email subject line takes only the first word upto the first space. From what I've found, this is a parsing issue & have discovered the following line that *should* help.

```
polNo = Chr(34) + Replace(polNo,chr(34),chr(34)&chr(34))
```

The above line places all of the text in quotes (I know this because my SendKeys line now shows the GetText result with a " at the start.

The issue is when I reach the mailto line as Outlook pops up a window saying:

"The command line argument is not valid. Verify the switch you are using."

My end result will be an email that has a subject & a body with text taken from various parts of the screen.

**Solved**: Thanks to dmc below, he started me on the right line.

However, the solution was not to use Chr(34) but to use something as simple as:

```
polNo = Replace(polNo," ","20%")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it might not look like it, you're constructing a URL.  As such, the contents of that URL must be URL Encoded.  Certain characters can't be included in a URL, including a space.  Those characters are represented with a percent sign followed by the ASCII code of the character in hexadecimal.  For example, a space is changed to `%20`.

See the link below for a VBScript routine that will URL encode and decode strings.
http://www.justskins.com/forums/wsh-equivalent-of-server-38778.html

Edit: Although this is commonly known as URL encoding, the thing you're constructing is technically a URI.  [Wikipedia has a good page that explains further.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've attempted a few combinations of yout suggestion & got the same outcome as above. Either a subject/body with just the first word or the Outlook error message. I've used: polNo = Chr(34) + Replace(polNo,chr(34),polNo & "20%"), polNo = Replace(polNo, Chr(34), polNo & "%20") and many other combinations.

Comment: Try `polNo=Replace(polNo, " ", "%20")`.  That will replace spaces with the `%20` constant.  If you have any other characters in polNo that can't be put into a URL, you'll need to replace those, too.  For example, if you do expect to have a double-quote character, do this also: `polNo=Replace(polNo, Chr(34), "%22")`